# Why is my new and newly stained deck showing all dirt and grime that doesn't come off with soap and water?

Tags: deck, sealant

I built a deck about a month ago. It was primed and stained with a solid stain. I am noticing that all the shoe prints from the dirt are showing up. I have tried watering it down, adding soap, and even scrubbing it with a brush but it does not come out. Should I be using a sealant?

Comment: Which product was used. Not all stains are suitable for a surface receiving foot traffic.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you edit a picture or two into your post? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.